# C# How would set the output of this to a string?

Tags: c#, tcp

So this is a section of code for my tcp client. This part is to convert the bytes recieved into characters. However, i would like to put some logic to it and to do that i need to set this output to a string. As it keeps printing out every character individually how would i do this? If you require anymore information feel free to ask.

```
byte[] bb = new byte[100];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
  Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
```

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Well what encoding do you want to assume, for a start? You could use `string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 0, k)` for example, but not if it's not ASCII...

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, if you want to decode a byte array in a particular encoding, just use [`Encoding.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring). For example:

```
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 0, k);
```

(Note that ASCII is rarely a good choice if the text is meant to be arbitrary human text. UTF-8 is usually a better option at that point, but then you need to bear in mind the possibility that a single character may be split across multiple bytes - and therefore multiple calls to `Stream.Read`.)

Answer (score -1):

```
string str = "";
foreach (byte b in bb) str += Convert.ToChar(b);
Console.Write(str);
```

Comment: That's a *horribly* inefficient way to do it. See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: @JonSkeet , It may be a horrible way. However, it seemed to have done what i required. Thank you James

Comment: @JoshuaHodson: There are lots of things that might work, but would be a bad idea. It's better to find that out sooner rather than later - particularly for performance problems like this, where you may well find it's fine in small tests, but then you let it loose in larger situations and your server grinds to a halt. Beyond the performance, it's simply not the idiomatic way of converting binary data to text, IMO.

Comment: @JoshuaHodson: from one beginner to (possibly?) another, you're welcome. Given the question was unanswered at the time, a functional answer might be worse than an optimal one, but better than none.